# How to enable quiet build using automake?

Tags: automake

Imagine the following target and command generated by autoconf:

```
.c.lo:
    $(LTCOMPILE) -MT $@ -MD -MP -MF $(DEPDIR)/$*.Tpo -c -o $@ $<
    $(am__mv) $(DEPDIR)/$*.Tpo $(DEPDIR)/$*.Plo
```

I'm looking for a way in Makefile.am to manipulate that command, knowing that the command is generated by autoconf and I don't know what it is. In theory, something like this:

```
if BUILD_QUIETLY
    Q=@
endif

.c.lo:
     $(Q)$(autoconf-command-for-c-lo)
```

Or something like this (this is similar to Linux kernel's build output):

```
quiet_cmd_cc = CC     $@
      cmd_cc = $(autoconf-command-for-c-o)

.c.o:
    $(call cmd,cc)
```

Where `cmd` is a function that executes `cmd_$1` and either prints `quiet_cmd_$1` or `cmd_$1` based on a variable.

I looked for this on the internet, but most of the websites talk about the basics of autoconf. There doesn't seem to be any questions related to this here either.

Is this even possible?

Comment: `autoconf` doesn’t create Make rules. `automake` does. I’d suggest retagging. – Also, have you tried the `silent-rules` option to automake?

Comment: Also see http://www.flameeyes.eu/autotools-mythbuster/automake/silent.html (in particular section 3.2 “Custom silent rules”, if `silent-rules` isn’t enough for your needs).

Comment: @chirlu, thanks a lot for the pointer! I'd try it out and let you know.

Comment: @chirlu, this works great. Please write it as an answer so I'd accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per [chirlu's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421641/how-to-manipulate-the-generated-target-command#comment25302921_17421641), automake has an option to generate quiet output builds.

[This page](https://www.flameeyes.eu/autotools-mythbuster/automake/silent.html) has the necessary instructions. In short, put the following in `configure.ac`:

```
AM_SILENT_RULES([yes])
```

To then disable it, either do:

```
make V=0
```

after configuration, or:

```
./configure --enable-silent-rules
```

on configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can always pipe the output to /dev/null:

```
./configure 2>&1 >/dev/null
make 2>&1 >/dev/null
```

Comment: It's not about not getting any feedback from `make`. It's about making it output something that's easy to follow.